# Dynamodb adding to a list if the item already does not exists in that list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I want to add a item in a attribute which is a list, if that item does not already exists in the list of that attribute.
Is there any way I can write the same in UPDATEEXPRESSION?

I need below like result the order of item does not matter:

```
[1,2,3,4]+[5]=[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4]+[3]=[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4]+[3,5]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: what have done so far to solve the issue?,  supply a minimal example  of the code that isn't working

Comment: Potential solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030981/add-to-list-only-if-string-doesnt-already-exist-in-dynamodb-table

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB supports a [few types of Attribute Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) including sets.

You can use the three sets (Binary Set (BS), Number Set (NS), or String Set (SS)) to safely `ADD` an item. The [updated item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) will be the union set of the existing set and the new one:

> If the existing data type is a set and if Value is also a set, then Value is added to the existing set. For example, if the attribute value is the set [1,2], and the ADD action specified [3], then the final attribute value is [1,2,3]. An error occurs if an ADD action is specified for a set attribute and the attribute type specified does not match the existing set type.